# How to choose a mission for only two people?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am playing GTA V with a friend in a private session. (We don't like to have other real players in our session.)
We would also like to play the missions provided by Lester. But now we always get a mission for 4 players (jailbreak) and so we do not have a chance to go further on this, because we would like to play in pairs. Is there a way to choose only 2 player missions or skip the jailbreak mission?

Comment: The first heist is the only one that can be played with 2 people. Sorry to bring the bad news :(

Comment: sad. when inviting other players we always get gunmans, who are trying to kill us. not very funny. thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm going to write this as an answer. When it's done, please mark it as an answer so that other users can benefit from this information.

Answer (score 2):

Only the first heist can be played with 2 players. All of the other online heists require more players.

Comment: *Credit goes to Izzo for his comment*

Answer (score 1):

As Eat My Taco Crumbs stated,

> Only the first heist can be played with 2 players. All of the other online heists require more players.

But, you can always (There is actually a short cooldown before you can repeat a heist, this was added to slow down grinding money/rp) go back to "Fleeca Bank Job" (aka "Two Men Heist"), call Lester, click on "Replay Heist" (if it is disabled, first click on "Cancel Heist") and select the "Fleeca Bank Job", if it is disabled, please wait for a while.

In "The Jailbreak", you really need 4 players, as in finale, one must fly the "Velum Plane" ("Pilot"), one must protect the plane with an "Annihilator Battle Helicopter" ("Demolution"), and two must attack the jail, escaping the contact. ("Police Officer" and "Prisoner")

*Personal Opinion:*
All five heists are pretty fun and I think that the best thing to do is find another 2 people to play with you. Me and my friend pretty much do everything required in the heists, we just get people (auto invite and matchmaking) to get more money/rp and to fill the required person amount.

Also, I think that the easiest heist is the Humane Labs Raid and Fleeca Job, and the hardest is Jailbreak (Jail is full of enemies!). Also the Velum is pretty hard to fly.